# Radius-Property doesn't work in \tikzset (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikzset

Why doesn't the radius-property work in these case:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shadings, shadows, shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{my style/.style={fill=black!60,circle,radius=12cm, draw}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \node(newCircle) at (0, -12) [my style]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`radius` is not an parameter to nodes but to circles when using the `draw` command.
Instead, you'll have to use the `minimum width` parameter, with a value of the desired diameter:

[image: useless filled circle ;)]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shadings, shadows, shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{my style/.style={
    fill=black!60,
    opacity=0.5,
    circle,
    minimum width=24cm,
    draw}
    }
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (24,24);
        \node(newCircle) at (12,12) [my style]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```